# Bug in Eigen swap function on Intel compiler with O2+ optimization

Tags: c++, eigen, icc

I am using Eigen library in my program and it works incorrectly when compiling on in Intel compiler *(tested on Intel(R) C++ Compiler 18.0.222 [x86_64] Ubuntu 16)* with -O2/-O3 optimization level *(works fine with -O0 and in other compilers, like MS)*

What can be the reason?

Code to reproduce

```
ArrayXXf test(2,3);
float sumBefore = test.sum();
test.row(0).swap(test.row(1));
float sumAfter = test.sum();
float dif = abs(sumBefore - sumAfter);
assert(dif < 0.0001);
```

For example, I got `dif = 0.22`

Comment: your code snippet cannot compile: because of `auto`, `test` is a read-only expression generating new random values every time you evaluate it, and of course it cannot be swapped.

Comment: @ggael, sorry for my C++, I was tired. Now I have tested in this version.. and can't reproduce. Definitely, the problem was in the swap, I have calculated sum before and after the swap operation and it was very different, like 0.2. every time and only in release(with  O2) on Intel compiler in Ubuntu. In debug no problems. And on MS compiler no problems. And after changing swap to cblas_?swap no any problem in both release and debug. MB bug in compiler don't know.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of some bug on Eigen.swap function + Intel compiler.

It is hard to submit a bug to the Eigen so I will just leave it here so the information about the bug will be available for the search.

The workaround is, for example, to use [cblas_?swap from MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-cblas-swap)
that is working fine